# Artifacts with jar packaging which could be become bundles too accordind to some profile

Tags: osgi, apache-felix, bnd

I would like to ask you some hints about the proper way to configure maven in the following scenario:
I have some artifacts which are currently packaged as jar, but they have maven-bundle-plugin too because I want them become OSGI bundles, nevertheless I didn't change their package to bundle because it exists the case that I want build them as jar (or war sometimes).

To use maven-bundle-plugin with package jar I have followed [this chapter](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html#adding-osgi-metadata-to-existing-projects-without-changing-the-packaging-type) and all worked fine, but now I'm considering to package them with bundle, to gain the full features of maven-bundle-plugin and because my default deploy is to OSGI.

So I would like to know if packaging artifacts as bundles but using them in a not OSGI container may results in troubles, what do you think? Thx

Answer (score 0):

If you build your bundles using the alternative and newer plugin [`bnd-maven-plugin`](https://github.com/bndtools/bnd/blob/master/maven/bnd-maven-plugin/README.md) then it is not necessary to change the packaging type.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't seem so much mature. And please are you able to answer my last question?

Comment: The bnd-maven-plugin is mature and is used by many large organisations. What makes you think it's not mature? To answer your question: a bundle is a JAR file so yes of course you can use them outside OSGi.

Comment: Can you please say why you think it is not mature? It has been available for several releases and is from the Bnd developers.